# Best android layout for a set of columns

Tags: android, layout

On an Android layout, I'd like to have a set of rows, each with two TextViews. The leftmost column of TextViews should be right-aligned, just left of an imaginary centerline down the screen. The rightmost column should be left-aligned.

Examples of this can be seen at http://stuff.greenberg.org/ScopeCalc.htm

What's the best layout to use?

Answer (score 3):

IMO, TableLayout would be a logical choice with appropriate use of colspan/rowspan.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using LinearLayout, with the two sub-views of each row each getting 50% of the width.

Answer (score 0):

Using GridLayout you can apply columnspan and rowspan properties to the views inside the grid.